# How is "IT" pronounced in German? [eye-tee] or [ee-tay]?

Tags: pronunciation

I have worked in the IT (Information Technology) industry in Germany for over 15 years. I have always heard the acronym "IT" pronounced as in English [`eye-tee`], even when speaking in German.

My daughter is now in an "IT Grundkurs" at school and the teacher pronounces it with the German pronunciation [`ee-tay`].

1. Has anyone ever heard the German pronunciation of IT actually used?
2. Is there any definitive source where I could "prove" that the English pronunciation is standard, e.g. is there some kind of German linguistic association (such as in France the Académie française) which decides which pronunciation and spelling of even borrowed words is standard?

Comment: We have an german term for "IT", but it is oldfashioned and therefore rarely used: It is "EDV" (elektronische Daten-Verarbeitung)

Comment: And I always thought EDV meant "Erfahrung durch Verlust"... :-)

Comment: In German you don't usually use IT, you say "Informatik". IT you pronounce like you do in English [eye-tee].

Comment: Well, the term "Informatik" has some intersection with what is considered IT, but it doesn't cover all of it. Definitions vary, but hardware-related IT topics may possibly be closer to "Nachrichtentechnik".

Comment: Die Frage ist primär eine Meinungsumfrage und gehört geschlossen. Die Aussprache Ih-tee (deutsch) habe ich aber schon gehört und gesprochen - so heißen die Buchstaben hierzulande. Auch wenn manch einer Ju-Äs-Äi sagt ist Uh-Es-Ah geläufiger - bei FBI, CIA und NSA (sprich: Nasa oder Es-En-Äi) aber ist die amierkan. Aussprache üblich. Fazit: Kein allgemeiner Standard auszumachen.

Comment: @Quandary: "Informatik" is the scientific field (computer science). It has little overlap with (the professional occupation of) IT.

Comment: I have never heard "ee-tay" (Germanised: eh-täi). That's a weird one.

Comment: ee-tay is very, very common in the netherlands. interesting to see these answers for germany all favour eye-tee

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I never heard Germans (including myself) pronounce it other than `eye-tee`. I also think that this is the correct way to pronounce it since *Information Technology* is an English term and therefore should be pronounced English, not German.

However if IT ***would*** refer to *Informationstechnologie* it is a German word and should be pronounced German. Though *Informationstechnologie* **is** a correct German word I never heard it.

Comment: But I don't hear "Information Technology" either. It's always the abbreviation that's used, either pronounced in German or English.

Comment: I **read** *information technology* in english some times but never did so with *Informationstechnologie*. Instead,  germans often use *Informatik* to refer to the same field.

Comment: Did you ever hear *Informationstechnik* instead, perhaps? I’ve heard and read both.

Comment: I do hear and read *Informationstechnik* every now and then, yes.

Comment: Although on the German Wikipedia page for "Informationstechnik", it suggests only the English pronunciation of "IT": http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informationstechnik

Comment: a) Ich halte IT für Informations- und Telekommunikations~ (industrie, ...). b) Uh-Es-Ah wird auch meist deutsch ausgesprochen, obwohl es übersetzt VSA heißen müsste, was aber nur von exotischen Querulanten verwendet wird.

Comment: Da gebe ich dir Recht. Die verschiedene Aussprache kommt meiner Meinung nach daher, dass der Term *USA* zu einer Zeit bedeutsam wurde, als Englisch im deutschen Sprachraum nicht weit verbreitet war (zwischen erstem und zweiten. Der Term *IT* hingegen findet im Deutschen Sprachraum beim "gemeinen Volk" erst seit 2000 Anwendung; Englisch wird aber erst seit 1964 an deutschen Hauptschulen unterrichtet.

Answer (score 5):

I think both are used and both are correct. It's not like it's an exclusively English term; "IT" in German is also the abbreviation of "Informationstechnologie" (*Information* Technology, rather than *Internet* Technology).

You're likely to hear the English "eye-tee" more in international companies.

Answer (score 4):

There is no organisation that decides how words are to be pronounced in German, but the [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/IT) agrees with you, and that would be good enough for many people.

Answer (score 3):

The German equivalent for IT, which is pronounced 'eye tea' as previous answers suggest, is **EDV Elektronische Datenverarbeitung**. Depending on context of course but often you can use that to circumnavigate the issue.

Before the computing geeks go crazy: Yes they are not the same thing, but often used as synonyms, especially in a professional environment.

Answer (score 2):

The pronunciation of foreign-language abbreviations is an interesting topic, and of course, there is no right or wrong.

One abbreviation that, in my experience, has two "valid" pronunciations is IBM. Some say i-beh-äm, and others ei-bie-äm.

With IT, the odds are 9:1 for ei-tie vs. i-teh, IMHO (Stuttgart area)

Answer (score 0):

The German word "Informationstechnologie" in its abbreviated version is pronounced "eye-tee", i.e. English pronunciation.

A German pronunciation would be rather awkward. The non-abbreviated version is almost always German, however.